# A RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this context

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, user-defined-functions

[image]

SQL user Defined Function Error

Comment: Before posting a question, read documentation first!!!!  Clearly this is a syntax error.  It's part of programmer's job to debug their code.

Answer (score 1):

Try including parentheses:

```
create function namewithdesignation ()
returns varchar(100)
begin
    . . . 
end;
```

You can also include an `as` before the `begin`.